# Draw an IOSurface to an OpenGL context

Tags: opengl, gpu, osx-mountain-lion, osx-mavericks, core-image

I have an OpenGL context on which I draw successfully using OpenGL.

I need to draw a specific rectangle of an IOSurface to this context.

What is the best way to do this on 10.8?

*NOTE*: 
I know how to do this on 10.9 using CoreImage (by createing a CIImage from the IOSurface, and render it with `[CIContext drawImage:inRect:fromRect]`).
However, this does not work well for me on 10.8 (each raw of the image is displayed with a different offset, and the image is distorted diagonally).

**Edit:** Here is the code that works on 10.9 but not on 10.8:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceSRGB);

CIImage* ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithIOSurface:surface plane:0 format:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA options:@{kCIImageColorSpace : (__bridge id)colorSpace}];
NSRect flippedFromRect = fromRect;
// Flip rect before passing to CoreImage:
{
  flippedFromRect.origin.y = IOSurfaceGetHeight(surface) - fromRect.origin.y - fromRect.size.height;
}
[ciContext drawImage:ciImage inRect:inRect fromRect:flippedFromRect];


CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

Comment: Distorted diagonally? You are not by chance using an RGB image are you? This reminds me a lot of issues with data alignment... typically pixels have to be aligned on a 32-bit boundary, 24-bit image formats are a bunch of smoke and mirrors that the driver tries its best to hide from you. If you don't get the pixel pack/unpack state correct when you read/upload pixel data this magic behind the scenes stops being magic. This applies to some image file formats as well, such as DIB (`.bmp`) - each scanline is aligned to a 32-bit (`DWORD`) boundary.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, but I use 'BGRA' to create the IOSurface, and I could not find what I'm doing wrong with the alignment/pixel format, or why it does not work on 10.8. That's why I'm trying to use a lower level API.
My NSOpenGLPixelFormat attributs include {NSOpenGLPFAColorSize, 32,...} and it works find on 10.9. I use a CIImage to render a JPG to an IOSurface, process it in OpenCL to another surface, and this is the surface that I'm currently rendering using Core Image.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to draw the image in GL? I'm not sure whether you're using Core Image to give you an OpenGL texture handle for the surface, or if you are trying to upload the image data using something like `glTexImage2D (...)` that has added pixel transfer state / format conversion tied to it.

Comment: Yes, I added it to the result. I'm using Core Image to wrap the IOSurface and draw it in the current OpenGL context. I don't use CGLTexImageIOSurface2D but this could be another solution that does not use Core Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution by wrapping the IOSurface with an OpenGL texture and draw the texture to the screen. This assumes a similar API to `[CIContext render:toIOSurface:bounds:colorSpace:]` but a vertically flipped OpenGL coordinate system.

```
  // Draw surface on OpenGL context
  {
    // Enable the rectangle texture extenstion
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT);
    
    // 1. Create a texture from the IOSurface
    GLuint name;
    {
      CGLContextObj cgl_ctx = ...

      glGenTextures(1, &name);
      GLsizei surface_w = (GLsizei)IOSurfaceGetWidth(surface);
      GLsizei surface_h = (GLsizei)IOSurfaceGetHeight(surface);
      
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, name);
      
      CGLError cglError =
      CGLTexImageIOSurface2D(cgl_ctx, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, GL_RGBA, surface_w, surface_h, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, surface, 0);
      
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, 0);          
    }
    
    // 2. Draw the texture to the current OpenGL context
    {
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, name);
      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
      glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
      
      glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      
      glColor4f(0.f, 0.f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
      glTexCoord2f(   (float)NSMinX(fromRect),    (float)(NSMinY(fromRect)));
      glVertex2f(     (float)NSMinX(inRect),      (float)(NSMinY(inRect)));
      
      glTexCoord2f(   (float)NSMaxX(fromRect),    (float)NSMinY(fromRect));
      glVertex2f(     (float)NSMaxX(inRect),      (float)NSMinY(inRect));

      glTexCoord2f(   (float)NSMaxX(fromRect),    (float)NSMaxY(fromRect));
      glVertex2f(     (float)NSMaxX(inRect),      (float)NSMaxY(inRect));
      
      glTexCoord2f(   (float)NSMinX(fromRect),    (float)NSMaxY(fromRect));
      glVertex2f(     (float)NSMinX(inRect),      (float)NSMaxY(inRect));
      
      glEnd();
      
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, 0);
    }
    glDeleteTextures(1, &name);
  }
```

If you need to draw in the display's color profile, you can explicitly call ColorSync and pass it your source profile and destination profile. It will return to you a “recipe” to perform the color correction. That recipe actually has a linearization, a color conversion (a 3x3 conversion matrix) and a gamma.

```
FragmentInfo = ColorSyncTransformCopyProperty (transform, kColorSyncTransformFullConversionData, NULL);
```

If you like, you can combine all those operations into a 3D lookup table. That's actually what happens in the color management of many of the OS X frameworks and applications.

References:

1. [Apple TextureUpload sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TextureUpload/Listings/MyOpenGLView_m.html)
2. [Draw IOSurfaces to another IOSurface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097015/draw-iosurfaces-to-another-iosurface)
3. [OpenGL Options for Advanced Color Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2313/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014694-CH1-NONCOLORMANAGEDFRAMEWORKS-OPENGL___EXPLICIT_COLOR_MANAGEMENT_EXAMPLE)